# Count specific key in json jquery

Tags: jquery, json

```
[
    {
        color: "red",
        value: "#f00"
    },
    {
        color: "green",
        value: "#0f0"
    },
    {
        color: "blue",
        value: "#00f"
    },
    {
        color: "cyan",
        value: "#0ff"
    },
    {
        color: "magenta",
        value: "#f0f"
    },
    {
        color: "yellow",
        value: "#ff0"
    },
    {
        color: "black",
        value: "#000"
    }
]
```

Counting json key varies from

```
function count(obj) {
   var count=0;
   for(var prop in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
         ++count;
      }
   }
   return count;
}
```

to

```
var keys = [];
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  keys.push(key)
});
// numberOfKeys should equal to 2
var numberOfKeys = keys.length;var keys = [];
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  keys.push(key)
});
// numberOfKeys should equal to 2
var numberOfKeys = keys.length;
```

But what if i have a specific key that i only need to count like in my sample count the number of `color` or count the number of 'red'.

1. Count the number of existing (specific) key `Example count color`
2. Count the number of existing (specific) value `Example count red`

Answer (score 0):

See the following code:

```
var json = [
    {
        color: "red",
        value: "#f00"
    },
    {
        color: "green",
        value: "#0f0"
    },
    {
        color: "blue",
        value: "#00f"
    },
    {
        color: "cyan",
        value: "#0ff"
    },
    {
        color: "magenta",
        value: "#f0f"
    },
    {
        color: "yellow",
        value: "#ff0"
    },
    {
        color: "black",
        value: "#000"
    }
]
```

Convert to string:

```
var str = JSON.stringify(json)
```

Count string using regular expression as follows(this is not a perfect regular expression, you can enhance it more, but this would work):

```
var colorCount = (str.match(/\"color\"/g) || []).length;//7

var redCount = (str.match(/\"red\"/g) || []).length;//1
```

Alternatively:

```
var countColor = 0;
var countRed = 0;
for (var obj in json) { 
    console.log(json[obj])
    var object = json[obj];
    if (object.hasOwnProperty('color')) {
        countColor++;
        if(object.color == "red") {
            countRed++;
        }
    }
} 
console.log(countColor);
console.log(countRed);
```

Edit:

if you fear that levels(nesting) of json could be larger than you think then you can use recursion for json objects.

Comment: I will try it out and i will be back on you after a while this while take more time for me

Comment: To test this code that whether it fulfills your requirement or not, you can place this on chrome's console and test the results.